# How to iterate over a map and return all the ones that match?

Tags: java

I have made various methods for someone to add a key which then includes various values from another created object.

I need to then allow a user to search using a method name which will then return all the people that match their search.

```
     public Set findPerson(String aTrade)
     {
        Set<String> suitablePeople = new HashSet<>();
     
        for (String test : this.contractors.keySet())
        {
           System.out.println(contractors.get(test));
           if (contractors.containsValue(aTrade))
           {
              suitablePeople.add(test);
           }
        }
        
        return suitablePeople;
     }
```

I know this code is wrong but I'm just not sure how I can simply go through and find a value and return all the people that have this value within a range of values. For instance, their age, job, location.

Comment: "I know this code is wrong..." How do you know? What does your code do when you run it? What do you want it to do instead?

Answer (score 1):

Some assumptions, because your question is rather unclear:

- `contractors` is a `Map<String, ContractorData>` field. Possibly ContractorData is some collection type (such as `MyList<Contractor>`), or named differently. The String represents a *username*.
- `aTrade` is a string, and you want to search for it within the various `ContractorData` objects stored in your map. Then you want to return a collection of all *username* strings that are mapped to a `ContractorData` object that contains a trade that matches `aTrade`.
- Whatever `ContractorData` might be, it has method `containsValue(String)` which returns `true` if the contractordata is considered a match. (If that was pseudocode and it's actually a `List<String>`, just `.contains()` would do the job. If it's something else you're going to have to elaborate in your question.

Then, there is no fast search available; maps allow you to do quick searches on their key (and not any particular property of their key, and not on their value or any particular property of their value). Thus, any search inherently implies you go through *all* the key/value mappings and check for each, individually, if it matches or not. If this is not an acceptable performance cost, you'd have to make another map, one that maps this property to something. This may have to be a multimap, and is considerably more complicated.

### The performance cost is not important

Okay, then, just.. loop, but note that the `.entrySet()` gives you both key (which you'll need in case it's a match) and value (which you need to check if it matches), so that's considerably simpler.

```
var out = new ArrayList<String>();
for (var e : contracts.entrySet()) {
    if (e.getValue().containsValue(aTrade)) out.add(e.getKey());
}

return out;
```

or if you prefer stream syntax:

```
return contracts.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().containsValue(aTrade))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .toList();
```

### The performance cost is important

Then it gets complicated. You'd need a single object that 'wraps' around at least two maps, and you need this because you want these maps to never go 'out of sync'. You need one map for each thing you want to have a `find` method for.

Thus, if you want a `getTradesForUser(String username)` as well as a `findAllUsersWithTrade(String aTrade)`, you need two maps; one that maps users to trades, one that maps trades to users. In addition, you need the concept of a multimap: A map that maps one key to (potentially) more than one value.

You can use guava's MultiMaps (guava is a third party library with some useful stuff, such as multimaps), or, you roll your own, which is trivial:

given:

```
class ContractData {
    private List<String> trades;

    public boolean containsValue(String trade) {
        return trades.contains(trade);
    }

    public List<String> getTrades() {
        return trades;
    }
}
```

then:

```
class TradesStore {
  Map<String, ContractData> usersToTrades = new HashMap<>();
  Map<String, List<String>> tradesToUsers = new HashMap<>();

  public void put(String username, ContractData contract) {
    usersToTrades.put(username, contract);
    for (String trade : contract.getTrades()) {
      tradesToUsers.computeIfAbsent(username, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(username);
    }
  }

  public Collection<String> getUsersForTrade(String trade) {
    return tradesToUsers.getOrDefault(trade, List.of());
  }
}
```

The `getOrDefault` method lets you specify a default value in case the trade isn't in the map. Thus, if you ask for 'get me all users which have trade [SOME_VALUE_NOBODY_IS_TRADING]', this returns an empty list (`List.of()` gives you an empty list), which is the right answer (null would be wrong - there IS an answer, and it is: Nobody. null is means: Unknown / irrelevant, and is therefore incorrect here).

The `computeIfAbsent` method just gets you the value associated with a key, but, if there is no such key/value mapping yet, you also give it the code required to make it. Here, we pass a function (`k -> new ArrayList<>()`) which says: just.. make a new arraylist first if I ask for a key that isn't yet in there, put it in the map, and then return that (k is the key, which we don't need to make the initial value).

Thus, `computeIfAbsent` and `getOrDefault` in combination make the concept of a multimap easy to write.

Comment: That is one great answer to one rather mediocre question :thumbsup

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Map's values are instances of `Contractor` and the `Contractor class` has a `Set<String>` of trades (implied by the contains method call) and a `getTrades()` method that returns the list you could do it like this. Not certain what value the Map key would play in this.

- get the values from the map and stream them.
- filter only those Contractors that have the appropriate trade.
- aggregate to a set of able contractors.

```
Set<Contractor> suitablePeople = 
                    contractors.values()
                               .stream()
                               .filter(c->c.getTrades().contains(aTrade))
                               .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Note that a possible improvement would be to have a map like the following.

```
Map<String, Set<Contractors>> // where the key is the desired trade.
```

Then you could just get the Contractors with a single lookup up for each desired trade.

```
Set<Contractors> plumbers = mapByTrade.get("plumbers");  // all done.
```

Here is how you would set it up.  The `Contractor` class is at the end. It takes a name and a variable array of trades.

```
Set<Contractor> contractors = Set.of(
        new Contractor("Acme", "plumbing", "electrical", "masonry", "roofing", "carpet"),
        new Contractor("Joe's plumbing", "plumbing"),
        new Contractor("Smith", "HVAC", "electrical"),
        new Contractor("Ace", "electrical"));
```

Then, iterate over the list of contractors to create the map.  Then those are grouped by trade, and each contractor that matches is put in the associated set for that trade.

```
Map<String,Set<Contractor>> mapByTrade = new HashMap<>();
for (Contractor c : contractors) {
    for (String trade : c.getTrades()) {
        mapByTrade.computeIfAbsent(trade, v->new HashSet<>()).add(c);
    }
}
```

And here it is in action.

```
Set<Contractor> plumbers = mapByTrade.get("plumbing");
System.out.println(plumbers);
System.out.println(mapByTrade.get("electrical"));
System.out.println(mapByTrade.get("HVAC"));
```

prints

```
[Acme, Joe's plumbing]
[Ace, Acme, Smith]
[Smith]
```

And here is the Contractor class.

```
class Contractor {
    private Set<String> trades;
    private String name;
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object ob) {
        if (ob == name) {
            return true;
        }
        if (ob == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (ob instanceof Contractor) {
             return ((Contractor)ob).name.equals(this.name);
        }
        return false;
    }
            
        
    public Contractor(String name, String...trades) {
        this.name = name;
        this.trades = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(trades));
    }
        public Set<String> getTrades() {
        return trades;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
    
}
```